# Logging out gives 404 error

Tags: errors, 404-error, logout

When I try to log out of my site, I'm taken to a 404 page, and the logout doesn't work. The url looks like this:

http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=4a09cb2887&redirect_to=http://www.mysite.com

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Heyyy wait a second, that url is fake! Try disabling all your plugins and see if that solves the problem. If it does, enable them one by one to find the root. Lengthy process but it's what I would do first.

Comment: It is not really possible to answer your question like this. Did you try deactivating all the Plugins? Do you have caching installed?

Comment: I don't have caching installed.